# How to build and submit Mac builds to Graphicall?

Tags: versions, osx

I've used a few of the custom builds on [Graphicall](http://graphicall.org/), and I'd like to give back by helping contribute some back. I've got a Mac, which is a bit of an underdog in terms of building submitted, and I've got decent experience with Subversion and other version control systems, but haven't seen a "how to" on compiling builds for others.

How do I set up a build environment on my Mac for compiling and bundling build packages to Graphicall?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are easy to follow steps clearly outlined on the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Mac). It tells how to setup the environment and how to download and build the source.

If you then go to [graphicall](http://www.graphicall.org/) and create an account, after logging in, there should be an option to upload a new build.

[image]

**Update:** To create an account on Graphicall.org, people now have to go to the IRC channel `#blenderstorm` on [freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/) and leave a request for an account *(just preferred username + email-address is enough)*. An admin will create the account when the request is received.

Comment: Aha, so building for Graphicall has nothing special other than just building Blender; I didn't realize the "how to set up a build environment" was there in the Blender wiki; thanks!