# How do I import a custom icon set in the theme options?

Tags: customization, theme

I'm trying to load a custom icon set, however Blender will not load it despite the fact that it's a modified version of the original SVG.

Comment: See related. [Can I use a custom Splash screen?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188/can-i-use-a-custom-splash-screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you can't.
In 2.67 there is a button in the theme preferences, but since this is non-functional its been removed for 2.68.

Note that you can of course build your own blender from source with modified icons and fonts but this is outside the scope of stack-exchange.

Comment: Agreed. At most OP can refer to [Can I use a custom Splash screen?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188/can-i-use-a-custom-splash-screen) or [How to build and submit Mac builds to Graphicall?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-to-build-and-submit-mac-builds-to-graphicall)